# Active Direcory "whenCreated" to MySQL datetime

Tags: php, active-directory

Is there a more compact and elegant way to convert Active Directory "whenCreated" values like "20141114120225.0Z" into a MySQL datetime format than the code below?

```
if(preg_match("/^(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/", $value, $m))
  $value = sprintf("%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s", $m[1], $m[2], $m[3], $m[4], $m[5], $m[6]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
<?php 
    // The regexp ensures only numbers were used
    $valueForMySQL = preg_replace("/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}).+/","$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6", $value);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that should do the trick using PHP's DateTime class.

```
/**
 * @param string $ldap_time
 * @param string $output_format
 * @return bool|string
 */
public function convert_ldap_time($ldap_time, $output_format)
{
    $format = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', rtrim($ldap_time, '.0Z'));
    if (!$format) $format = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymdhis', rtrim($ldap_time, '.0Z'));
    return ($format) ? $format->format($output_format) : false;
}
```

This would allow you to do something like:

```
$mysql_time = convert_ldap_time($whenCreated, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of rtrim in the convert_ldap_time function is not quite correct. For a value of $ldap_time='20160412182250.0Z' or any other value with a '0' before the period the function will return false. The second argument to rtrim is a mask of characters to remove so '0' get's trimmed too. One way to improve this would be to truncate the input at 14 characters and append back the 'Z' at the end. E.g.

```
$format = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', substr($ldap_time,0,14). 'Z');
```